# How can I create a trigger to update another table based on values on the table updated?

Tags: mysql, workbench

I have a table called `ROOM`. This table has `ROOM_ID`, `CLASS_ID` and other columns.

I have another table called `ROOM_HISTORY`. This table has `ROOM_ID`, `CLASS_ID`, `START_DATE`, `END_DATE`.

I want to create a trigger that inserts into `ROOM_HISTORY` when a `CLASS_ID` changes rooms (goes from one `ROOM_ID` to another `ROOM_ID`) in the `ROOM` table. It should insert a new row in `ROOM_HISTORY` table with the `CLASS_ID` that changed and its new `ROOM_ID`.

In addition, I want to update the old row in `ROOM_HISTORY` that has the old `ROOM_ID` to change `END_DATE`.

How can I do that?

Comment: ...why not just use Temporal Tables?

Comment: Please post your table schema and your trigger so far.  Start it off in the workbench and let us know where you get stuck.

Comment: Where does start and end date come from when inserting to room history - not from room by the look of it.

Comment: @P.Salmon stard and end date are manual inputs.

Comment: Triggers don't accept manual input - what do you mean by manual input?